# Javascript, jquery, backbone, splunk: on("change", {data}, handler) results in TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, splunk

I'm trying to watch (and change, if necessary) the selection of a multiselect on a dashboard in Splunk. For that, I fetch the multiselect in Javascript and listen to a "change" event on it. On change, I run a function that receives the multiselect in order to check and adjust the selection.

My code is roughly as follows:

```
// Get the multiselect
var multi1 = splunkjs.mvc.Components.getInstance("input1");

// Function to check selection
function smartSelector(container){
    var multi = container.multi;
    var selection = multi.val();
    if (...) {
        // Change selection
        ...
        // Set new selection to multi and refresh item
        multi.val(selection);
        multi.render();
    }
};

// On change, run function
multi1.on("change", function () {smartSelector({multi: multi1})});
```

This works fine. But from what I understand, there is a prettier way to define a handler and data for events, such as in this example from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_on_data):

```
function doIt(event) {
    alert(event.data.msg);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("p").on("click", {msg: "You just clicked me!"}, doIt)
});
```

However, when I apply this to my code like this:

```
// Fetch another multiselect
var multi2 = splunkjs.mvc.Components.getInstance("input2");

// Adjust function code to get event data
function smartSelector(event){
    var multi = event.data.multi;
    ...
}

// Adjust on("change", ...) to work with event data and handler
multi2.on("change", {multi: multi2}, smartSelector);
```

I get a `TypeError: (intermediate value).callback.call is not a function` at `mvc.js:6:108716`, which I think is a part of Backbone (as a part of Splunk).

What is the cause of this, and what can I do to achieve the correct behavior?
Thank you for your ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I think I got it.
The way to use `on(...)` is not as it is with [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/on/), but with [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on). You need to do it like this:

```
multi2.on("change", smartSelector, {multi: multi2});
```

Usually, you use the context value to set `this` in the function you call to another context which at first didn't sound like something I wanted. But it is exactly what I needed, so in my case I had to use the following code in smartSelector:

```
function smartSelector(){
    var multi = this.multi;
    var selection = multi.val();
    ...
```

Thank you squall3d for giving me the idea that I may not be using the correct `on(...)`!

Comment: Haha I'm still curious to know, does the event parameter in smartSelector have the currentTarget property? i.e. function smartSelector(event){ console.log(event.currentTarget);}

Comment: No, `event` isn't even defined (with `multi2.on("change", smartSelector, {multi: multi2});` that is). The way I understand it is that you can only reference the object you pass along this way with `this` inside the called function, so it's different from how you do it with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if splunkjs components implement the same signature for `.on()`, but if you are trying to get a reference to the element triggering the event, is there a `event.currentTarget` in smartSelector?

Comment: I don't know, as smartSelector is not called in the second example.
But I guess you're right, I can't just assume that `on()` is the same in splunkjs compared to the original - I'll go ask on that at splunk answers.